# Como fazer consulta dinamica usando select no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Eu tenho na minha view a com dashboard/index.

Essa index possui uma tabela e um gráfico que por padrão, ela traz informações do mês atual (primeiro e ultimo dia do mês).
Eu gostaria atualizar dinamicamente através do select que tem informações dos ultimos meses.

Route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', ['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'DashboardController@index']);
Route::post('/dashboard', ['as'=>'dashboard.buscapormes', 'uses'=>'DashboardController@buscapormes']);
```

index.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('dashboard.buscapormes') }}" >
            <select class="mesCorrente" id="mesCorrente" name="buscapormes">
               <option selected="selected" name="buscapormes" value="{{ $MesAtual }}">
        <?=$Mes."/".date('Y');?>
    </option>

        <option name="buscapormes" value='{{ $MesMenosUmMes }} '>
    <?=$MesMenosUm."/".date('Y');?>
    </option>
        <option name="buscapormes" value='{{ $MesMenosDoisMeses }}'>
    <?=$MesMenosDois."/".date('Y');?>
    </option>
<option name="buscapormes" value='{{ $MesMenosTresMeses }}'>
<?=$MesMenosTres."/".date('Y');?>
</option>
    </select>

        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
```

DashboardController.php

```
public function buscapormes(Request $req, $buscapormes)
    {
        //$registros = $req->all();
        //dd($registros);


        $title = 'Inffel OnBoard :: Dashboard';
        $subtitle = 'Dashboard';

        $ClienteID = auth()->user()->cliente_id; 

        $dataInicio = substr($buscapormes, 0, 10);
        $dataFinal = substr($buscapormes, 13, 10);      

        $dashboard=DB::table('MVE')
        ->select(DB::raw('DATA, sum(TOTAL) as TOTAL'))
        ->where('CLIENTE', $ClienteID)
        ->whereBetween('DATA', [$dataInicio, $dataFinal])
        ->groupBy('DATA')
        ->orderBy('DATA')
        ->get();


        return view('dashboard.index', compact('title', 'subtitle', 'dashboard'));
    }
```

Print de erro
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrNoD.jpg

Comment: Mas se fizer refresh dá o mesmo erro ? O controller está a ser chamado ? `dd($dashboard);` dá o resultado que você espera ?

Comment: Coloca sua resposta que está faltando o csrf no form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente esta mensagem é lançada quando você tentou enviar um formulário sem proteção ou já expirado.

Como você está fazendo o filtro usando o método `post` do formulário. Obrigatóriamente você precisa inserir o token CSRF do Laravel.

Abaixo segue um exemplo de como usar:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('index') }}">
  @csrf <--// isso aqui eh obrigatório no método post.

  <input type="text" name="filtro" />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```